# What is the better way to update array of nested object in React useState

Tags: reactjs, object, react-hooks, nested

I have a state with array of nested object in it. I need to update the state of checked value with the onChange event.

```
const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState();
```

And checkedState structure look like this:

```
[{Title: {Article: {checked: false, disabled: true}, Desc: {checked: false, disabled: false} }}, {News: {Dashboard: {checked: false, disabled: false}} }}];
```

I tried like this, but I think it can be made cleaner, please any suggestions...

```
 const handleChange = ({ target: { name, checked } }) => {
    setCheckedState(
      [...checkedState].map(object => {
        for (const checkboxProps in object) {
          if (object[checkboxProps][name]) {
            return {
              ...object,
              [checkboxProps]: {
                ...object[checkboxProps],
                [name]: {...object[checkboxProps][name], checked}
              }
            };
          }

          return {...object, [checkboxProps]: {...object[checkboxProps]}};
        }
      })
    );
  };
```

Comment: take a look at `.reduce` function. This looks like a perfect use-case for it

Comment: And also at immer.js. It's perfect for nested updates.

Comment: Okay, thx, I'll try, how do u think @JSEvgeny can I use Object.entries instead of "for in"?

Comment: You can use it like this (extracting key and value from array of entries) `Object.entries(object).map(([key, value]) => ...)` or `Object.entries(object).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ...)` with reduce